# How to enable/use SNMPv2 RowStatus feature on pysnmp if new row indexes aren't known on table creation?

Tags: snmp, pysnmp

I'm implementing a NTCIP agent using pysnmp with lots of tables containing SNMPv2 RowStatus columns.

I need to allow clients to create new conceptual rows on existing agent tables, however there is no way to know the indices of such rows before their creation. Consequently, I can't create such RowStatus object instances on pysnmp. Without this instances, the client have no object to issue a SET command in order to add a conceptual row to the table.

Is there any way to handle this on pysnmp? Perhaps a column generic callback mechanism or something similar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have found the problem on creating new rows.

The original (ASN.1) mib file defines all RowStatus columns as **read-write**, but pysnmp MibTableColumn createTest method fails if symbol access permission is not **read-create**. Changing the RowStatus definitions on the MIB source solved the problem.

After doing that I could create new rows, but noticed another issue: a snmp walk on the table caused a timeout. The problem is that pysnmp doesn't know which values to put on new row elements which are not indices and do not have default values defined, so it puts None - which causes a 'Attempted "__hash__" operation on ASN.1 schema object' PyAsn1Error. In order to handle this the client must issue SET commands to every field in the newly created row before getting them OR add default values to column objects (not sure about that, but default values are not populated by mibdump as original ASN.1 mibs never define default values of itens which are not optional, by definition). My code to  export columns for my StaticTable class follows (incomplete code, but I think some method and attribute names speak by themselves).

```
def add_create_test_callback(superclass, create_callback, error_callback=None):
    """Create a class based on superclass that calls callback function when element is changed"""
    class VarCCb(superclass):
        def createTest(self, name, val, idx, acInfo):
            if create_callback and val in [4, 'createAndWait', 5, 'createAndGo']:
                superclass.createTest(self, name, val, idx, acInfo)
                create_callback(name, val, idx, acInfo)
            else:
                if error_callback:
                    error_callback(name, 'optionNotSupported')

                raise error.NoCreationError(idx=idx, name=name)

return VarCCb

class StaticTable:
    # ....

    def config_cols(self):
        """Add callback do RowStatus columns and default values for other columns that are not indices"""
        MibTableColumn, = self.mib_builder.importSymbols('SNMPv2-SMI', 'MibTableColumn')

        _, column_symbols = self.import_column_symbols()

        for index, symbol in enumerate(column_symbols):
            if symbol.syntax.__class__.__name__ == 'DcmRowStatus':
                # add callback for row creation on all row status columns
                MibTableColumnWCb = add_create_test_callback(MibTableColumn, self.create_callback,
                                                               self.error_callback)
                # setMaxAccess needs to be defined, otherwise symbol is defaulted as readonly
                new_col = MibTableColumnWCb(symbol.name, symbol.syntax.clone()).setMaxAccess('readcreate')
                named_col = {symbol.label: new_col}
            elif index >= self.index_n and self.column_default_values:
                new_col = MibTableColumn(symbol.name, symbol.syntax.clone(self.column_default_values[index]))
                named_col = {symbol.label: new_col}
            else:
                new_col = None
                named_col = None

            if new_col:
                self.mib_builder.unexportSymbols(self.mib_name, symbol.label)
                self.mib_builder.exportSymbols(self.mib_name, **named_col)

    # ...
```

Not sure if this is the right way to do it, please correct me if I am wrong. Maybe I shouldn't include this here, but it is part of the way to solving the original question and may help others.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think with SNMP in general you can't remotely create table rows without knowing their indices. Because index is the way how you convey SNMP agent the information where exactly the row shall reside in the table.

In technical terms, to invoke `RowStatus` object for a column you need to know its index (e.g. row ID).

If I am mistaken, please explain how that would work?

The other case is when you are not creating table row remotely, but just expose the data you already have at your SNMP agent through the SNMP tables mechanism. Then you can take just build the indices off the existing data. That would not require your SNMP manager to know the indices beforehand.

The possible mid-ground approach can be if your SNMP agent exposes some information that SNMP manager can use for building proper indices for the table rows to be created.

All in all, I think the discussion would benefit from some more hints on  your situation. ;-)

Comment: The client knows the indices of the row it wants to create, the agent is the one who doesn't. So the client must issue a SET command to an RowStatus instance which wasn't created yet by the agent (as the agent doesn't know the OID beforehand). So the question is: on pysnmp, how to handle the RowStatus SET command when the RowStatus instance object wasn't created prior to the command? For an existing instance I would overwrite the MibScalarInstance writeCommit method, but in this case I just can't find how to handle the SET command. Thank you!